# Format DateTime issue for Millisecond level with FileHelpers C#

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, filehelpers

I need very small help for parsing the date time data from csv file by FileHelpers Library using C# application.

The Date Time data I have used in csv files as = 20160803T0509+0100

I am getting the error as below

```
ex = {"Error Converting '20160803T0509+0100' to type: 'DateTime'.  There are more chars in the Input String than in the Format string: 'yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss'"}
```

I am using the code as below

```
    [FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth, MultilineMode.NotAllow)]
                [FieldTrim(TrimMode.Both)]
                [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss")]

 private DateTime _ShipmentDateTime;
                public DateTime ShipmentDateTime
                {
                    get { return _ShipmentDateTime; }
                    set { _ShipmentDateTime = value; }
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `"yyyyMMdd#HHmm#####"` as the format string?

Comment: Did you get this issue solved @susheeltyagi?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to do some string manipulation as `DateTime.Parse()` or `DateTimeOffset.Parse()` won't understand: "20160803T0509+0100"

you will need to look for the "T" and remove it, count 2 characters on and put a ":" also you will need to find the "+" and count 2 characters and put a ":".

That would get you something like this: `"20160803 05:09 +01:00"`.
If you know that it is formatted as YYYYMMDD in the csv file add "/" at the relevant positions to get: **`"2016/08/03 05:09 +01:00"`**

Now, DateTimeOffset.Parse() will understand this string.

```
public DateTime ShipmentDateTime
 {
   get { return _ShipmentDateTime; }
   set { 
         var dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.Parse(value); //value = "2016/08/03 05:09 +01:00"
         _ShipmentDateTime = dateTimeOffset.UtcDateTime; 
       }
 }
```

**Side Note:**

*Is there any particular reason you are using Datetime over DateTimeOffset as shipping is multi-time-zone and DateTimeOffset is generally safer to work with. You could always convert to DateTime at a later stage for display purposes, but at least you still have the offest significant figures.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the format `yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz`. The `zzz` handles the timezone information. The full attribute you need to use is:

```
[FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz")]
```

The [documentation](http://www.filehelpers.net/mustread/) states that "*You can find all the supported format strings in the MSDN docs for [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)*" so you can prove the above with a simple app ([DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TOsjAB)):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("20160803T0509+0100", "yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
Console.WriteLine(d);
Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmzzz"));
```

Which produces (on my UK system)

> 03/08/2016 05:09:00
>   20160803T0509+01:00